# How to submit a data array to an reactjs app by url

Tags: reactjs

my react level is very low and I am searching for a solution for this:

Right now, I open a react app by an url: http://localhost:3000/campaigns/create?param1=abc&param2=123&param3=abc123. The url params contain data from a caller outside my app. This works fine for one entity of data params from the url. I parse it to an json object, like so:

```
{
  "param1": "abc",
  "param2": "123",
  "param3": "abc123"
}
```

What do I do, if the caller wants to submit 1 to n entities by calling the url in the browser, so that I get an result object as array:

```
[{
  "param1": "abc",
  "param2": "123",
  "param3": "abc123"
},{
  "param1": "abc",
  "param2": "123",
  "param3": "abc123"
}]
```

What is the common way to send data to an url, without calling http endpoints from inside the react app? I use react 16.10.

Comment: Can't you use http "POST" ?

Comment: No, I can not use POST, since I am always in the client.

Comment: As I learned so far, there basically is no way to POST data to a browser client, without a backend. HTTP does have a request body for GET request, but it is not recommended to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeat the parameters:

```
http://localhost:3000/campaigns/create?
param1=abc&param1=abc&param2=123&param2=123&param3=abc123&param3=abc123
```

Now, you'll get the array of parameters:

```
param1 = ['abc', 'abc'] // and like so
```

---

It is better to indicate users/api that parameter contains value of array:

```
param1[]=abc&param1[]=abc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that would work. But in my case I actually want to get rid of the url parameters. (That is not clear in the question I asked)

Comment: Your comment made me surprise then. You would need to use POST request.

Comment: You are right. What I found out since two days of intense research, that there is no way of submitting data as a GET request to the client, beside the url itself and url params, like you pointed to. So your answer helped me a lot.